# With Orbeon Forms, why are my submissions to a server using a self-signed certificate failing?

Tags: xforms, orbeon

When running submissions (`<xforms:submission>`) over HTTPS against a server that use a self-signed certificate, I am getting an exception in the logs that looks like:

```
ERROR XFormsServer  - XForms - submission - xforms-submit-error throwable: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException 
: unable to find valid certification path to requested target 
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174) 
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238) 
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:280) 
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:191)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When making the HTTPS request, Java checks the certificate of the server. Because the certificate is self-signed, Java can't verify it is a legitimate certificate, hence the error message "unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

What you need to do is either:

1. Use a "real" certificate (e.g. signed by Verisign).
2. Add the certificate of your server to a "trust store", and setup your JVM of application server use that trust store.

The exact steps for doing #2 above will depend on your environment, but in essence:

1. If the server handling the requests has its self-signed key in a Java key store, export it. Here `your-server` is the alias for your server the key store, `mykey.cer` is the file you are creating, `keystore` is your key store file, and `your-password` is the password to your key store.

   `keytool -export -alias your-server -file mykey.cer -keystore keystore -storepass your-password`
2. On the server on which Orbeon Forms is running (i.e. the server that initiates the HTTPS request), import `mykey.cer` into a trust store. Here `truststore` is your trust store file, which might be a new file you are creating if you don't have an existing trust store.

   `keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias your-server -file mykey.cer -keystore truststore -storepass your-password`
3. Add the following `-D` parameters when starting the VM that runs your application server (e.g. Tomcat) and Orbeon Forms:

   `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path/to/your/truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=your-password`